# why my UIDocumentPickerViewController returns me a url not reachable?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am using a uIdocumentPickerViewController to upload a pdf file in firebase but when I try to upload it, I get an error saying that this file is not reachable.

Here is the code of the delegate of my uidocumentPickerViewController :

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

            let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference()
            print(urls.first!)




            storageReference.child((urls.first?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent)!).putFile(from: urls.first!, metadata: nil){(_, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                    return
                }

                print("success")
            }


        }
```

Here is the mistake I get after choosing my pdf file :

File at URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/7BE40C45-A4B5-4EE0-8AFF-789B2F93C1F6/File%20Provider%20Storage/Document%20PDF.pdf is not reachable.

Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using UIDocumentPicker like below and it works fine:

First I have an enum,

```
enum UploadFileType{
    case photo
    case file
}
```

Then a structure:

```
struct UploadFileData {
    var fileName: String
    var fileType: UploadFileType
    var fileData: NSData
}

var file: UploadFileData?

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path))
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: url.path)
    guard let doc = data else {
        //  Utility.showAlert(message: Strings.ERROR.text, title: Strings.DOCUMENT_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED.text, controller: self)
        return
    }
    self.file = UploadFileData(fileName: "\(url)", fileType: .file, fileData: doc)
    guard let dataFile = self.file?.fileData as Data? else {return}
}
```

Comment: I used the same thing as you but it is not working. when I print the url I get this one : file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads/attestationHebergementSofianeBenslimane.pdf

Comment: What url do you get ? Maybe it's not working for me because of the private

Comment: "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/678EFAE9-CB5E-4524-859E-3608FEqw123/tmp/se.Jarja-Inbox/abdulkarimkhan_resume.pdf"

Comment: I also have private in my url, and it works fine. @sofiane_dv Try implementing the way I have using file manager.

Comment: ok thanks you very much for you help I created a new project and it worked. I don't know what I did wrong previously

Comment: @sofiane_dv That’s great! All the best (Y)